# Specific device fails to layout correctly

Tags: android, android-framelayout

Hey there I have an issue, that currently one user reported, on a `non-rooted` device `Micromax A110Q (hdpi)`  `android 4.2.1` it fails to `MATCH_PARENT` on the `content view` or the `decor view`

Here here is a comparison of what you can see on the device and on emulator (with exactly the same density and resolution and android version)

[image]

I've sent the user `APK` that generates a report about the views, you can see them below (both device and emulator)

[device more detailed report](http://pastebin.com/hQMX6brD)

[emulator more detailed report](http://pastebin.com/BB4VVaA4)

screen height is `854px`, without statusbar its `816px` but its measured `619px` on users device (on emulator it's `816px`).

```
decor view <height: match parent>
---- FrameLayout <height: match parent>
-------- FrameLayout (android.id.content) <height: match parent>
------------- FrameLayout <set match_parent but height: **619**>
----------------- DrawerLayout <height: match parent>
----------------- ToolBar <height: 50dp>
-------- ViewStub (not used)
```

what are those `197px` \ `131dp`? they are not padding or margins

P.S I've tried to reset the layoutparams height manually after the layout to height `816px` but it was ignored and reverted back to `619px`

**I know it must be a bug with the Micromax A110Q 4.2.1 firmware, but how can I work around that?**

Comment: Hello , can you share your layout.xml pls ?

Comment: The layout is dynamically created so there is no just a single xml file.(unfortunately I can't post them here) Note that the match `DrawerLayout` is in the aosp, and there is no way it won't match the parent currently. But If you have specific question feel free to ask

Comment: Try using dp instead of px , but it's bad solution to set a fixed hight .

Comment: @wSakly the px you see are just the raw pixels measured by the device, I don't actually set the size at this stage at the hierarchy

Comment: Sorry for that , can you try to change the FrameLayout (That contain drawer and toolbar) to LinearLayout and change the toolbar in Top .

Comment: This things works perfectly on all devices I've encountered so far, but not on this one. I'm looking for a work around.